# Bcrypt not consistently comparing passwords in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

I'm comparing the same plainTextPassword and hash in two different programs right now using bcrypt and one is telling me that the passwords match and the other is saying that they don't.

In the problem file:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username,plainTextPassword,done) {
  process.nextTick(() => {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?',[username],(err,rows) => {
      if (err) return done(err);
      if (!rows[0]) return done(null,false);

      let hash = rows[0].password;
      let user = rows[0];
      bcrypt.compare(plainTextPassword, hash, (err, res) => {
        console.log(plainTextPassword);      // test
        console.log(hash);                   // $2b$10$EefqCwYTMHDDtIGH.SIHIu.BPCOiT7Bp4Zzej5iUoxlKtMZ67oHtC
        console.log(res);                    // false
        if (!res) return done(null,false);
        return done(null,rows[0]);
      });
    });
  });
}));
```

I am copying the logged values of plainTextPassword and hash and pasting them into this code:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
bcrypt.compare('test', '$2b$10$EefqCwYTMHDDtIGH.SIHIu.BPCOiT7Bp4Zzej5iUoxlKtMZ67oHtC', (err,same) => {
  console.log(same);    // true
}
```

and this is returning true, rather than false like the `console.log(res)` of the first code block returns. The first code block has been checking most passwords fine, but this one seems different. There are no special characters, the plainTextPassword is 'test' and the hash is stored in a VARCHAR(150) in the mysql database.

Comment: `no special characters` what about encoding, etc?  Purely plaintext?

Comment: You're ignoring errors in the bcrypt callback?

Comment: It's stored in the database using `utf8 - default collation` if that matters. Not sure how to correctly answer your question other than say that I hashed the text in a script written in VSCode, copied the hash from bash, and entered the hash into the database. Now when I query my login endpoint the bcrypt function fails. @TheIncorrigible1

Comment: @Bergi the `err` object just logs as `undefined`

Comment: What NodeJS and Bcrypt version are you using? Could you check: `hash.trim().length === hash.length`?

Answer (score 0):

See [](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt: "The cost parameter specifies a key expansion iteration count as a power of two, which is an input to the crypt algorithm"

$10$ specifies a cost parameter of 10, indicating 2^10 key expansion rounds.

Of course the code line: `const saltRounds = 10;` is not used, remove dead code.